# How to write a function of total price

Tags: invoice

I am using a function to show custom information on an invoice:  (app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/invoice.php)

```
public function customtext($page)
{    
    $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('custom text '), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Added at end of invoice.php, and `$this->customtext($page);` added to end of `public function getPdf($invoices = array())` above `$this->_afterGetPdf();`

But I want to include in my custom text the value of 20% of my invoice Grand Total.  How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can pass yo your function the `invoice` object you are displaying you can do it like this:

```
public function customtext($page, $invoice)
{    
    $price = $invoice->getGrandTotal() * 20 /100;
    $order = $invoice->getOrder();
    $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__($order->formatPriceTxt($price)), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Comment: Looks good but I get error - Call to a member function getGrandTotal() on a non-object

Comment: also getting errors - Call to a member function getOrder() on a non-object & Call to a member function formatPriceTxt() on a non-object.  I added more specific details to my coding in the above queston

Comment: that's because $invoice is not an object in your case. I explained that this works only if you can pass the invoice parameter to your method

Comment: I needed to change $this->customtext($page); to customtext($page, $invoice); when calling the function